# Does sitecore have any preferred or suplied font delivery system?

Tags: fonts, sitecore, typography

From what I recall CQ5 has some typekit integration, was wondering if anyone knows if sitecore supplies any sort of type rendering system, or if there are any best practices / convenient aps or methods for font rendering in sitecore?

Comment: None of the above. You'll have to integrate the old fashoined way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the front-end for modern Sitecore is typically either ASP.Net Web Forms or ASP.Net MVC. You'd use the same methods for delivering anything related to the front-end as you would with either of those two frameworks.

Recently I've been using [System.Web.Optimization](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification), but I've also had good experiences with using NodeJS as a build system to use Bower for front-end dependencies for similar content management systems and I think that would also work well with Sitecore.

Comment: Have you worked at all with reactJS.net? Not about typefaces, but was just reading about it, seemed like a cool front end solution for sitecore stuff.